# Content is not displayed properly

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: Feeds section]

In Feeds section,  the content is not getting displayed properly. Plz refer image. Mostly starting content is not displayed

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: 2014818

  - OS Version: 4.4.4 (V7.1.1.0.KHJMICK)